# Chat room owner abuses powers - any recourse?

Tags: support, chat

There is a room owner in [the Python chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/6/python) who kicks members out of chat for fairly trivial reasons.

The last one I witnessed was him kicking a member out for not using correct punctuation, a user had put an extra space character between a word and a question mark.  Apparently he was "warned" about this in the past, so it seems to be a common annoyance for this particular room owner.

I mentioned that we should not force our own pet peeves onto others, and it's better to lead by example, but that was not well received.  I do think it's a good feature for room owners to be able to kick out disruptive or annoying chat members, but what can we do if/when a user is abusing that privilege?

Comment: s/privelege/privilege   You can get kicked from meta for such transgressions:)

Comment: Start your own room.

Comment: This seems something you need to discuss with the person in question.

Comment: @Tunaki  unfortunately that's not an acceptable alternative, you might want to chat with other members in the existing room and you can't reasonably expect them all to come and join a new room

Comment: If the RO is such a tyran, they will leave and join your new happy room!

Comment: Could you provide transcript links demonstrating this behaviour? That isn't what I'd expect from the Python room, though I admit it's now been a while since I was watching it.

Comment: @gunr2171  irrespective of whether you agree or disagree with this particular example, the question stands for any rogue room owner, hypothetical or not

Comment: @Tunaki That's not a thrilling suggestion. There are de-facto semi-official rooms per-tag, with a supermajority of active users in that area. Creating a new room is a possibility, but it's preferable to resolve conflicts instead of splitting people up.

Comment: Can't you bring it up with the other RO's.  If there are no other RO's then it is solely his room and he can do what he wants(within the SO rules, no hate speech please).  If you do not like you do not have to be there.

Comment: @wim here is a recourse. Have a chat with him

Comment: @JeremyBanks  sure, [transcript](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/29678343#29678343)

Comment: Normally I look at these complaints as people just being thin-skinned, but this is different. If this was some random room this guy created, I'd say tough crap - but this appears to be the main room for Python and that makes this worth looking at. I consider myself rather rigid when it comes to grammar, but this is chat. People are going to spell things wrong. The RO needs to lighten up since they are coming off as a holier-than-thou neckbeard.

Comment: As an RO of the Python room I believe there's more context to what's alluded to in this post. David's aware of this meta post and I'm sure when he's got a moment he can fill in the gaps.

Comment: @JonClements There's certainly two sides to every story, but there really are no gaps to fill in here. I'm not saying he doesn't have any right to help enforce some standards, but what wim is saying that being the "main" Python chat it really should hold itself to a standard of "not being a pretentious grammar nazi" instead of "people that use pronouns incorrectly are getting kicked". Sort of makes the whole lot look bad, really. It's a chat room, not a Congressional hearing.

Comment: This is pretty unacceptable. Kicking someone for putting spaces inbetween punctuation or not capitalizing a word is absurdly authoritarian. I expect such a RO to kick himself from the room any time he has a grammar/spelling mistake. In fact, davidism didn't end most of his sentences with periods, and at one point used a comma where he should have used a semi-colon! Where was the self-kick?!

Comment: wow.... @JonClements I will refrain from judging before the "full context" but if you scroll up in the link Wim gave, it does look like davidism just warned a guy once for one extra whitespace, and then kicked him. I honestly HOPE there is more to it than just that... because as it looks now, it looks.... bad

Comment: In Python the correct number of spaces is crucial. To take it as far as when speaking *about* Python is ... overly zealous? (The mildest euphemism for "anally retentive" I can come up with.)

Comment: What's next, banning people for words that are too [tinny and not wooden enough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-gwXJsWHupg)? This entire thing is petty and extraordinary silly (and *not* on the part of the OP).

Comment: Excuse my French but what a porkis.

Comment: @Patrice: The link wim gave isn't _everything_. There's a little more in the room's [transcript](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/6/2016/3/31/18-21). The linked transcript is just some moved messages.

Comment: @cerbrus Wim is not talking about HIS kick though, is he? He's debating the first kick. Which you agree is out of place. For that, the transcript he posted is enough. If we talk about Wim's kick... then yeah that's another deal. He poked the bear­. The bear should've been more civil, but you shouldn't poke one anyway.

Comment: I don't personally know said RO, but I've seen some of his contributions over the course of time I've been here and although I feel he is a really good contributor to this site, I do agree that the first kick was a bit extreme and authoritarian, maybe he was just having a bad day guys. Can we give him the benefit of the doubt?

Comment: @JustDoIt Not when the kick was meted out after a period of "warnings" not to do it. That's intentional behavior.

Comment: Come on, kicking out someone for missing a space it's a bit radical. @TylerH

Comment: @JustDoIt Yes, *I agree*. Hence this question and my unwavering stance that the RO was out of line. So you're agreeing with me? Or what? To be clear, I was responding to your "Can we give him the benefit of the doubt" question. AKA, "Can we give him the benefit of the doubt?" "No"

Comment: Oh okay, I thought you were just not agreeing with me hehe ^^, @TylerH I always tend to give the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: If a room owner is intolerant of being called out for inappropriate moderation, and takes to abusing power to persecute critics, especially when they have a monopoly on a tag, then perhaps that room owner should be given a break from room ownership duties for a while. That's not as extreme as the conclusion of the top and accepted answer below, but it seems about right. Kicking people from chat with high reputation levels who are calling the room owner out for abuse of power only incredibly strengthens their argument.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The moderators behaviour is discriminatory against non fluent English speakers and therefore should not be treated as acceptable. They are essentially refusing to let other members take part on the basis of their English skills.

As with the rest of Stack overflow, the chat rooms should be considered as community resources and somebody who has contributed to it should not be able to be denied access for petty grammar mistakes.

A ban of their chat room privileges would be appropriate to let this user know that their behaviour is inappropriate.

Comment: The RO asked someone to fix the punctuation, first. It's not a "skill" to change how you write. Revoking RO status for something as trivial as a single kick is quite excessive.

Comment: for people who are not fluent in english, applying the correct rules of grammar every time is a skill. It was the RO who acted excessively

Comment: I'm not defending that first kick. But it's not a "skill" not to add a space before punctuation. It's got _nothing_ to do with the language you're using. _Punctuation_ doesn't require "skill". _Grammar_, on the other hand, does require practice.

Comment: @Cerbrus "It's got nothing to do with the language you're using." To take but one example, French punctuation rules are such that one must put a space before and after question marks and exclamation points. Someone who is much more at ease in French than English might sometimes apply the rules they are more familiar with, and end up writing English with French punctuation. Now, maybe your an amazing person that can automatically switch from ruleset to ruleset flawlessly all the time. A lot of us are not so fortunate. Remembering what rules to apply in what context certainly **is** a skill.

Comment: @Cerbrus, how are your punctuation skills in Mandarin or Russian ?

Comment: @Louis: The french are universally recognized as silly ;-) "Not adding a space" isn't _hard_ especially if you've just friendly been reminded not to. Sure, you can slip up every now and then, and I don't think the RO in question acts on slip-ups. But immediately after being reminded?

Comment: @Jaco: I'm sure I can remember to add punctuation where it should and shouldn't go in those languages. Just tell me where the sentences start / end, where the periods go and whether or not to add spaces. Did I mention straw man?

Comment: As an analogy, I primarily use c# but occasionally have to use VB.NET. I naturally want to add semi colons at the end of statements and occasionally make that mistake. This is not because I don't know the VB.NET syntax or cant remember but just because of the context switch between the language i'm used to and the other.

Comment: ... and then the compiler / IDE tells you not to do that, and you remember for the rest of the day, right?

Comment: @Cerbrus No: and then you do it again .

Comment: And then you get frustrated by the IDE nagging about semicolons, so you turn off the syntax checker?

Comment: @Cerbrus: ;semicolonlivesmatter

Answer (score 18):

As a room owner I'm basically powerless, and a room owner abusing their powers must be a comedy.

Chat is the third-place, and with that it is hardly moderated; almost anything goes there, and only when things really get out of hand will either moderators or the CM team steps in.

On MSE there is this post [Toward a philosophy of Chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270587/toward-a-philosophy-of-chat) that explains the context of chat. Additionally there is [A guide to moderating chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271267/a-guide-to-moderating-chat).

The Python room is always used as an example of how chat rooms should be run, and I have copied the good parts.

It takes two to tango, and chat is really limited in both expression and verbiage, especially if a room chooses to build theirs on [cabbage](http://sopython.com/salad/?highlight=Cabbage%20%2F%20cbg).

You have three options:

- Mention in the room that you're confused by the action. Either someone will explain or they will keep your opposition in mind next time.
- Invite the user to a new room and explain one-to-one what is troubling you. By listening, asking questions, and summarizing each others view points, you'll reach a common understanding .
- Put it on the agenda for the next room meeting. Gather examples of exchanges where you feel things went beyond your acceptance level.

Be prepared to agree to disagree; there is too much diversity going on, and too many different sub-goals for each individual to be aligned on every thing. Learn to live with that fact.

Notice how my three options don't include bringing it to meta. The culture and what is and isn't accepted in a room is often only barely understood by room regulars, let alone the meta crowd.

Sometimes the best option is to click [leave] at the top-right of the chatroom menu and sleep over it. A new day might bring matters into a better perspective.

[Watermelon](http://sopython.com/salad/?highlight=Watermelon)

Comment: You may have intended to answer the question "how odd are Python people?"

Comment: Basically powerless? Room owners can kick users and move messages out of the room, too. That's pretty powerful.

Comment: @TylerH You can't do any permanent damage, it is annoying at best for the user involved

Comment: @rene Give me RO for ten minutes to demonstrate, and you can clean up the resulting mess.

Comment: Well, clearly few people seem bothered by all this.  Personally, I would be incensed if someone kicked me out of a chat room because I put a space before a question mark (if that is, in fact, what happened here).  Also [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320204/chat-room-owner-abuses-powers-any-recourse#comment328845_320209).

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm not saying you shouldn't be incensed.  I'm only offering a sensible way out of such non-sense, de-escalate instead of bringing more fuel to the fire. And yes, I also like taking a stab at the Python room. I leave it to others if they have a similar sense of humor, that isn't an universal emotion afterall.

Comment: Please don't assume all users active in the python tag are weirdos, just because the bunch in the python chat room can be odd and cliquey :)

Comment: @wim I don't assume anything, I'm open minded, don't worry about me.

Comment: Yeah, not all of us are weirdos. Just those who use tabs for indentation.

Comment: @AndrasDeak you monster! (:D)

Comment: @RobertHarvey: From what I can see in the transcript, wim got kicked because, instead of simply debating the kick, he went out of his way copying the behavior that got the first guy kicked. He provoked the RO and got booted. Then he went to Meta complaining about power abuse.

Comment: @Cerbrus It's my interpretation that wim is bringing up the RO's initial kick of another user as abuse. If he then kicked wim for doing the same thing, that just adds credence to wim's complaint.

Comment: _"Annoying an RO on purpose"_ is a valid reason to kick, though.

Comment: @Cerbrus Annoying *anyone* on purpose is a valid reason :) (just to make the distinction that ROs aren't special butterflies)

Comment: _"As a room owner I'm basically powerless, and a room owner abusing their powers must be a comedy."_ - **Not true**. Being able to "mute" others by deleting their posts or kicking them *is power*.

Comment: _"click [leave] at the top-right of the chatroom menu and sleep over it"_ - In blatant cases of power abuse (like the one in the OP) it should be discussed with ROs. If they choose not to take the appropriate action with phrases like "oh stop being a drama queen" (some regulars call it drama when the offender is a regular, and "rule enforcement" when the offender is a non-regular) , the issue should be brought to Meta.

Answer (score 14):

If you have an issue with a particular room owner in a room, I suggest you bring it up with the other room owners as they should have a say in how the room functions.  If they agree with you that the behavior is out of line, they can talk to the room owner and adjust the behavior.

If there is only one room owner then you are out of luck there.  It is their room so they can do what they want as long as it does not violate any Stack Overflow policies.  If it does then you can mod flag.  If it is all above board but the room owner is being a tyrant, then I suggest you just leave or ignore the room.

Comment: *"It is their room so they can do what they want as long as it does not violate any Stack Overflow policies."* I do not agree with this in all cases. For small-ish rooms, fine. But when you're talking about the by-far-largest room associated with a tag, we should hold the owners to some degree of reasonable behaviour. If, *as alleged*, users were kicked for minor grammar mistakes and nothing else (I don't know whether that's actually the case here), then that's something the community-at-large should be concerned with.

Comment: I think Nathan is talking about the case "if there is only one room owner" there.  Obviously this is thinking of the general case, not the one room linked.

Comment: @JeremyBanks I preceded that with *If there is only one room owner then you are out of luck there* which is important.

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't think that's relevant. I would hold the same position if there were a single room owner, and I would hold the same position if there were multiple owners who all supported the inappropriate action. It's the history and significant of the room that is of greater importance. Room ownership is like post ownership: the owner has the greatest say, but the community can overrule them in severe cases. That's the nature of Stack Exchange.

Comment: @JeremyBanks If there is a single room owner then it is there room.  They can do what they want no matter how many other people are in/use the room.

Comment: I think your suggestion is good.  Thanks.

Comment: @NathanOliver The creator of something doesn't necessarily always retain ownership of that thing. Especially with community constructs.

Comment: @TylerH True.  but the way SO is structured the creator of a room has basically full control over what happens in the room until they decide to add other RO's.

Comment: That's true, but as currently constructed, I think a single owner room remains "theirs" in some sense although iirc a mod can make someone else a room owner (e.g. if an "important" room goes dormant)

Comment: This article springs to mind when reading this: https://sethvargo.com/stackoverflow-is-full-of-children/

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't think anyone's debating how the rules are now, but rather how they *should be*. We're well aware that RO's have a final say. But in big rooms, that *shouldn't be the case*, even if it is the case at the moment.

Comment: @Rob: And that's when you contact other room owners, so they can sort out the mess with the RO that was originally involved.

Answer (score -41):

Note: I'm not defending that first kick. The RO could've handled it better as well. But if you're fined by a cop and you disagree, you don't jump on the grass and tell the cop he's wrong, *even if he is*. You appeal it through official channels. In this case, a discussion with other ROs would've sufficed.<sup>[1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320204/chat-room-owner-abuses-powers-any-recourse#comment329114_320266)</sup>

Step one: Don't go stepping on a room owner's toes.

Looking at the moved messages' [transcript](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/71097/2016/3/31) and the room's [transcript](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/6/2016/3/31/18-21), a user [was asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/29677391#29677391) to [fix his punctuation](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/29677622#29677622), then got kicked when he didn't.

You responded that the kick was unwarranted (Which is fine. I'm not defending the punctuation kick). The only problem is that you did the exact thing you were complaining didn't warrant a kick, while complaining about the kick.

That's like shouting at the cops that trampling on the grass isn't something someone should be fined for, while you're stomping your feet on said grass. Honestly, what did you expect?

If you want to discuss policy with a room owner, they usually are open to it. Just don't be obnoxious about it, by "violating" the exact rule / action you're debating.

Wim was even told in the room to discuss it with other room owners:

> *"@wim I don't think meta is the right place to discuss these issues. The correct thing to do is discuss with other room owners"* [(source)](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/29679256#29679256%5C)

His response:

> *"disagree.  it's a failing of stack exchange chat if one room owner can enforce their whims onto others"* ([source](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/29679263#29679263))

This isn't "Power abuse".
You provoked a RO and got kicked, then made a meta post complaining about the RO, leaving out details in your complaint.

Basically, my point is:
If you disagree with an RO's actions, discuss it without provoking the RO like that. That's all there is to it.

Comment: Apparently I'm wrong. I'd love to get some responses explaining why. -6 without a single comment is a little disappointing. If I'm misrepresenting what actually happend, I'd like to know so I can correct my answer here.

Comment: I can only speak for myself, but you're saying it was not power abuse, after introducing with *Don't go stepping on a room owner's toes* and before following with *You provoked a RO and got kicked*. I find that quite contradictory. It seems you're advocating pandering to the room owners regardless of their behavior -- I disagree.

Comment: (As an aside, power plays like this are the main reason why I've been *very* reluctant to chat since the IRC days waaay back in the nineties. Apparently the situation hasn't changed at all in twenty years. You probably won't see me in an SO chat room anytime soon.)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: I'm not saying we should pamper room owners. If they're out of line, they should be "dealt with". I'm just saying wim didn't exactly put any effort into de-escalating the situation (actively refusing to discuss it with other ROs), _then_ went to meta to complain when he got kicked, leaving out some details. He could've handled it _way_ better.

Comment: Perhaps, but kicking a user because of *an extra space before a punctuation mark* is just plain silly. I would say the room owner could also have handled the situation way better, and the blame lies on them because they're a room owner and we're supposed to expect a better attitude from them in the first place.

Comment: Once again, I'm not defending that first kick. The RO could've handled it better as well. But if you're fined by a cop and you disagree, you don't jump on the grass and tell the cop he's wrong, _even if he is_. You appeal it through official channels. In this case, a discussion with other ROs would've sufficed.

Comment: Your answer is basically inline with my answer, only yours is much better formulated. My answer also had initial down votes but order has been restored now...

Comment: @rene: The comment is appreciated :-) Maybe users are a little more tempted to go for the downvote since I'm not being very subtle in here.

Comment: You've probably received downvotes because you are addressing this in a way that makes it sound like you side with the RO who abused his powers. AKA "don't step on the RO's toes and you won't get booted", sort of akin to victim blaming AKA "don't walk down the dark alley in a short skirt and you won't get sexually assaulted". Well, was it wise to do it? Probably not; a safer course of action probably existed. But should you have been kicked/assaulted just because you spaced out your punctuation/wore a skirt down an alley? Definitely not.

Comment: Basically what Frederic's comment says.

Comment: Cerbrus, I feel your post might be received better if it began with [this comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320204/chat-room-owner-abuses-powers-any-recourse#comment329114_320266). Maybe edit it in?

Comment: @CubeJockey: go for it :-)

Comment: @TylerH: I don't think the comparison with rape is fair here. That's why I used the grass / cop example, as I think it represents the situation better. Provoke an authority figure and you will get bitten. That still doesn't make the authority figure right, but the "subject" _was_ doing something _wrong_, compared to just wearing a skirt, which _isn't wrong_.

Comment: @Cerbrus "provoke an authority figure and you will get bitten" authority figures are elected or placed in positions of authority precisely because they *won't* bite when provoked, actually. With great power comes great responsibility; we expect our leaders to exemplify the best in us. And that means not kicking people for failing to follow an idiotic rule.

Comment: Being an RO _does_ make that person an authority figure in that room. Once again, I'm __not defending the RO__'s actions. I'm just saying the __RO is not the only one that handled the situation poorly__.

Comment: I agree with this post (though I understand why people are getting a bad vibe and downvoting). The escalation of this incident appears to have been a multi-party failure.

Comment: @Cerbrus I never said that the RO was not an authority figure in their room, I'm saying the RO's behavior is inappropriate for an authority figure. And I agree with you, both parties could've handled it better. But that doesn't mean it's a 50/50 fault split... more like an 80/20 split... against the RO.

Comment: I don't intend to point my finger one way or another a specific amount... This whole situation is ridiculous and could easily have been avoided. I'm sortof proud I managed to write such a low scoring answer, though. ;-)

Comment: @Cerbrus Well, I disagree that it could've been easily avoided :-) Since the kicked user (not OP here, but the first victim) was not antagonizing the RO intentionally (or, IMO, at all; the RO was just a dick). But I agree that the whole situation is ridiculous.

Comment: Why not? If the RO hadn't kicked anyone, or if the OP hadn't antagonized the RO, we wouldn't have had this discussion, methinks.

Comment: _"If you disagree with an RO's actions, discuss it without provoking the RO like that. "_ - ROs are not police officers. The person arguing with ROs in a chat room is no potential threat to their life, so they don't need to respond as a police officer. And the RO's reaction to such criticism is the very reason those type of disputes should be brought to Meta where everyone (not just people that are emotionally connected to the offending RO - and therefor biased) can judge the situation.

Comment: @Fermiparadox: Room Owners are owners of the specific room. They're allowed to enforce the room roles as they see fit, within SE's rules, of course.